# WebRTC - Chrome black remote stream

Tags: javascript, signalr, webrtc

I am trying to put together a little video-chat prototype using WebRTC.

I've been testing this on localhost for the last couple of days (using 2 browser instances) but I simply can't get chrome(V32) to display the remote stream correctly as it is always a black square.

I can see the streams arrive to both peers, get attached but always black.

In firefox (V26) everything works very well.

I am using SignalR as the signaling mechanism and adapter.js for browser interoperability.

This is the code I have for the webrtc module, what can I possibly be doing wrong for chrome to fail?

Thank you very much.

```
define(['services/logger', 'services/dataservice', 'services/messenger', 'knockout'], function (logger, dataservice, messenger, ko) {

    var
        webrtc = {
            init: init,
            call: call
        },
        _myMediaStream = null,
        _myConstraints = null,
        _myConnection = null,
        _iceServers = [{ url: 'stun:74.125.142.127:19302' }]; // stun.l.google.com - Firefox does not support DNS names.


    function init(constraints) {
        getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {

            var videoElement = document.querySelector('#myVideo');
            //videoElement.muted = true;
            videoElement.controls = true;
            _myMediaStream = stream;
            _myConstraints = constraints;

            attachMediaStream(videoElement, _myMediaStream);

            messenger.publish('LocalMediaStreamSet');

        }, function (error) {
            logger.logError(JSON.stringify(error), null, 'webrtc/init', true);
        });
    }

    function call(user) {
        _myConnection = _myConnection || _createConnection();

        _myConnection.addStream(_myMediaStream);

        _myConnection.createOffer(function (desc) {

            _myConnection.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
                dataservice.sendRTCMessage(JSON.stringify({ sdp: desc, origin: '', target: user, constraints: _myConstraints, type:'offer' }));
            });
        });
    }

    function _createConnection() {
        console.log('creating RTCPeerConnection...');

        var connection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: _iceServers }); // null = no ICE servers

        connection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
            if (event.candidate) {
                dataservice.sendICECandidate(JSON.stringify({ "candidate": event.candidate }))
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('ice candidate sent to remote peer.')
                });
            }
        };

        connection.onaddstream = function (event) {

            var videoElement = document.querySelector('#theirsVideo');
            videoElement.controls = true;
            console.log('attaching remote stream...')
            attachMediaStream(videoElement, event.stream);
            console.log('attaching remote stream done.')
        };

        connection.onremovestream = function () {
            console.log('Remote stream removed.');
        };

        return connection;
    }

    function _subscribeToEvents() {
        //subscribe to new RTCMessage events
        messenger.subscribe(document, 'newRTCMessage', function (e, message) {
            var
                isConfirmed = true,
                connection = _myConnection || _createConnection();

            if (message.sdp.type === 'offer') {
                //need confirmation to accept the call
                isConfirmed = confirm("Incoming call from " + message.origin + ", accept?");
            }
            if (message.sdp && isConfirmed) {



                connection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), function () {
                    if (connection.remoteDescription.type === 'offer') {

                        //subscrive to localstream when ready (is setted on the init call below)
                        messenger.subscribe(document, 'LocalMediaStreamSet', function (e) {
                            console.log('received offer, sending answer...');

                            connection.addStream(_myMediaStream);

                            connection.createAnswer(function (desc) {

                                connection.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
                                    dataservice.sendRTCMessage(JSON.stringify({ sdp: connection.localDescription, origin: '', target: message.origin, callId: '', type: 'answer' }));
                                });
                            });
                        });

                        init(message.constraints);

                    } else if (connection.remoteDescription.type === 'answer') {
                        console.log('got an answer');
                    }
                });
            } else if (message.candidate) {
                console.log('adding ice candidate from remote peer...');
                connection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
            }

            _myConnection = connection;
        });
    }

    _subscribeToEvents();

    return webrtc;

});
```

Comment: What is inside attachMediaStream method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Igor. The attachMediaStream method is part of the adapter.js library that you can check out here https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js?r=4259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work!!

It had to do with the fact that on connection.onicecandidate event I should be calling the dataservice.sendRTCMessage() function instead of the dataservice.sendICECandidate() one that was failing on my controller.

Both peers were not attaching remote ice candidates and thus the stream could not be shared.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Can you share tutorial or example code about your working example ?